# closedxml to datatable without looping

Tags: c#, excel, datatable, closedxml

at work I've used closedXML in the past to go from a datatable or dataset to excel extremely quickly without looping. Now I need to go the other way but the only documentation I can find on closed XMl or anything else to go from excel to datatable is to loop. I can't imagine with the current demand for speed, the large amounts of data that can go into excel and the widespread use of Office that nobody has figured out a faster way than looping.

Is there a way in closed XML or another reasonably sized, safe library that quickly moves excel to datables or other system.data objects such as datasets  without looping?

Comment: I'm sure there are loops in the internals of ClosedXML. I don't think it is avoidable, even if it is abstracted from you.

Comment: Why do you want to avoid loop in the first place ?

Comment: looping is incredibly slow

Comment: @Crowcoder I'm sure there are too, but something the internal ClosedXML loops are exponentially faster than explicit loops through a datatable. I' looking for the same kind of speed up the other direction is all

Comment: I refer you to `XLCell.cs` of project ClosedXML in the source code where a DataTable passed in as IEnumerable to method `InsertTable` is looped over with a regular `foreach`. At a glance, there are even about 10 other loops within the main one. Loops are not slow, algorithms are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a plain OleDb connection to read data from a worksheet into a `DataTable`:

```
string strExcelConn = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=c:\filename.xlsx;Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;'";
using (OleDbConnection connExcel = new OleDbConnection(strExcelConn))
{
    string selectString = "SELECT * FROM [CA$A1:D500]";
    using (OleDbCommand cmdExcel = new OleDbCommand(selectString,connExcel))
    {
        cmdExcel.Connection = connExcel;
        connExcel.Open();
        DataTable dt=new DataTable();                    
        OleDbDataAdapter adp = new OleDbDataAdapter();
        adp.SelectCommand = cmdExcel;
        adp.FillSchema(dt, SchemaType.Source);
        adp.Fill(dt);
        int range=dt.Columns.Count;
        int row = dt.Rows.Count;
    }
}
```